# Unable to extract the entire value of pandas cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that has values in a column like this
[image]

When I read it in a df and print it, it looks like this:
[image]

I understand that it is unable to pretty print it but when I try to extract value of x y width and height then on height it gives list index out of range

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("./data/SSCARDTemplate.csv")
for i in df["region_id"]:
    coor = df.loc[df["region_id"] == i, "region_shape_attributes"]
    dic = coor.to_string().split(",")
    print(coor.to_string())
    x = dic[1].split(":")[1]
    y = dic[2].split(":")[1]
    w = dic[3].split(":")[1]
    print(dic[4])
    h = dic[4].split(":")[1]
    break
```

This is reproducible pandas example

```
{'#filename': {0: 'SSCARDTemplate.jpg',
  1: 'SSCARDTemplate.jpg',
  2: 'SSCARDTemplate.jpg',
  3: 'SSCARDTemplate.jpg',
  4: 'SSCARDTemplate.jpg',
  5: 'SSCARDTemplate.jpg'},
 'file_size': {0: 110231,
  1: 110231,
  2: 110231,
  3: 110231,
  4: 110231,
  5: 110231},
 'file_attributes': {0: '{}', 1: '{}', 2: '{}', 3: '{}', 4: '{}', 5: '{}'},
 'region_count': {0: 6, 1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 6, 5: 6},
 'region_id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5},
 'region_shape_attributes': {0: '{"name":"rect","x":402,"y":640,"width":521,"height":93}',
  1: '{"name":"rect","x":399,"y":723,"width":523,"height":88}',
  2: '{"name":"rect","x":402,"y":803,"width":526,"height":98}',
  3: '{"name":"rect","x":399,"y":889,"width":531,"height":101}',
  4: '{"name":"rect","x":404,"y":982,"width":526,"height":91}',
  5: '{"name":"rect","x":402,"y":1062,"width":529,"height":96}'},
 'region_attributes': {0: '{}', 1: '{}', 2: '{}', 3: '{}', 4: '{}', 5: '{}'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert strings repr of dicts to dictionaries by `json.loads`, so if pass to `DataFrame` constructor get columns:

```
import json

df1 = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(x) for x in df['region_shape_attributes']])
print (df1)
   name    x     y  width  height
0  rect  402   640    521      93
1  rect  399   723    523      88
2  rect  402   803    526      98
3  rect  399   889    531     101
4  rect  404   982    526      91
5  rect  402  1062    529      96
```